# How to access funds using CLI on Eth Network?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I'd created a multisig account on Gnosis-Safe to receive funds on the Polygon network.

The sender sent USDT to the address by mistake without realising that the asset type isn't supported in Polygon.
Then, I created the same address on Eth Network. I'm able to see the funds against this address on Etherscan. But, unable to access it on Safe UI (since USDT isn't showing up) for any transactions.
How can I access these funds?

Support team suggested that I access funds through CLI. I'm looking for developer support for the same.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this:

- The indexer didn't know about your Safe when you transferred in the funds (can be solved by transferring in the same token again, no matter what amount)
- The indexer doesn't support your singleton (should be displayed in the UI)
- Your Safe doesn't exist on the target network (UI should show an error and no code should be visible on the block explorer)

To provide more details it would be required to share the Safe address.

Edit: To transfer out the assets you can always use the transaction builder